# Reverse print only words in a given string ,number should not be reversed, i need alternate methods to perform the same

Tags: java, string, reverse, codemirror

**Reverse print only words in a given string ,number should not be reversed**

**Given String :** Testing 23 a 42 testing

**Expected output :** gnitseT 23 a 42 gnitset

i have used this Method

```
        public class ReverseString{
        public static void main(String[]args){

        String str= "Testing 23 a 42 testing";
        String[] split = str.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            try {
                Integer val = Integer.valueOf(split[i]);
                System.out.print(val);  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                for(int j=split[i].length()-1;j>=0;j--) {
                    System.out.print(split[i].charAt(j));
                }
            }
        if(split.length-1>i)System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**
gnitseT 23 a 42 gnitset

Comment: If your expected output matches your actual output, what is your question? Also, `if (split[i].matches("\\d+")) {`

Comment: need alternate methods to perform same operation.

Answer (score 1):

Tokenize the input. I would prefer `\\s+` to start by splitting on *consecutive* whitespace. If it isn't the first token, emit a space. Use a *regular expression* to determine if the token is all digits (`\\d+`), if so emit it. Otherwise, emit the reverse token. After iterating all of the tokens print a newline. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Testing 23 a 42 testing";
    String[] split = str.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        if (split[i].matches("\\d+")) {
            System.out.print(split[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.print(new StringBuilder(split[i]).reverse());
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
gnitseT 23 a 42 gnitset
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Java streams:

```
    String str = "Testing 23 a 42 testing";

    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(str.split(" ")) //
        .map(s -> s.matches("\\d+") ? s : new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString()) //
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

Comment: It looks really short and works fine. but it takes 3 times more duration than previous methods.  I dont know why...